# Brackets editor - shortcut to create an open/closed set of brackets

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

In TextMate there is a very useful shortcut where you hit CMD+SHIFT+W and it opens a

```
<p></p>
```

with your cursor over the p; you then type anything you want, and it will adjust it, e.g.

```
<h1></h1>
```

Brackets has auto-close but I loved the one-stroke simplicity of the Textmate shortcut, and am trying to replicate in Brackets, but I can't find the shortcut/extension to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean [adobe-brackets] tag instead of [brackets]?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two extensions for Adobe Brackets that implement keyboard shortcuts for markup generation, but do not exactly replicate TextMates behaviour.

[Quick Markup](https://github.com/redmunds/brackets-quick-markup), which was created by one of the core developers of Brackets, adds a panel to the editor that enables you to quickly format the selected HTML, much like the StackOverflow post editor. In addition, it provides a number of keyboard shortcuts for inserting paragraphs, headings and other things.

If you need more advanced shortcuts, then you should definitely check out [Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet) (formerly known as zen coding).
It allows you to write CSS-like selectors that generate markup and provides
a vast amount of tools for editing and navigation around markup.